# ReactJS: how to access all child components in parent component?

Tags: children, reactjs

Suppose I've got `comments` list component with `comments` components. I wanna implement method that will return all `comments` components. I assigned to each `comment` component same ref:

```
<comments>
 <comment ref="myComments" text="abc" />
 <comment ref="myComments" text="efg" />
</comments>
```

I thought I can access all my components by `this.refs.myComments` but it doesn't work - it returns only last comment component.

What's the correct way to access all `comment` components?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, really?

Comment: Suppose I've got comment. I wanna find rendered component for this comment.

Comment: I'll elaborate, normally using `ref` isn't preferred. Usually it's a sign that you have state that belongs somewhere else, so the question becomes more like "what are you trying to do with your children once you have them?"

Comment: Within the `comments` component you can access its children with `this.props.children`.

Comment: Just a fyi, `this.props.children` returns the descriptors and not the actual mounted component instances. Hence you shouldn't be calling methods on these children directly since that's very unstateful design

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this, it's not recommended either: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct way to do that.

Your view is a representation of your data, so if you want the text for all comments, look at the data.

If you want to update the comments, update the data.

Pulling data out of the view, or manually manipulating the view defeats the purpose of react.