# Get child property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components: `Cell` and `Screen`. `Cell` is intended to be a child of screen, I'm going to use them like this:

```
<Screen>
  <Cell x={1} y={2}/>
  <Cell x={1} y={1}/>
</Screen>
```

The question: How I can get `x` and `y` props inside `Screen`'s `render` method? Something like this:

```
render() {
  var {children} = this.props
  children[0].x // it doesn't work
...
```

Comment: In general, try to send information or state down into children, rather than having children send them up to their parents.

Comment: ^^ agreed, try storing the cells' x/y properties in the Screen component or above it, and pass these values down to the Cells.

Comment: Yep, it's nice as a general advice. But we have a concrete case. What the interface do you propose instead?

Comment: To keep code maintainable, pass anything that `<Screen>`  needs as a prop to `<Screen>`, and leave the children alone. Also, you should **not** update props. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610392/reactjs-how-to-access-all-child-components-in-parent-component

Comment: have you heard of flux?

Comment: Flux is an architecture concept for building application. I want to create a component. But As I said I'm open for proposition, what interface do you propose instead?

Comment: This is a legit question. There are use cases when you need to get, let's say, child's key to use inside of parent's iterator when you build some advanced wrapper component.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to access them through `props`, in most of the cases. Like:
`children[0].props.x`.