# I'm building a component that dynamically generates tabs, can't figure out how to pass in titles to dynamically name those tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a menu/navbar component I'm building that dynamically generates tabs for each of the children components passed into it.

Everything works properly the only issue I'm running into now is that I can't figure out how pass in titles to also name the tabs.

Right now I'm just generically rendering `Tab 1, Tab 2, etc.` but I'd like to pass in a title for each child component and have the tab display that value instead so like:

```
<Tabs>
  <div title={"Overview"}>
    <h1>This is the Overview tab</h1>
  </div>
  <div title={"About"}>
    <h1>This is the About tab</h1>
  </div>
</Tabs>
```

This is my current Tabs Component:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Tabs = (props: Props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);
  const childrenList = React.Children.toArray(children);

  const generateTabs = (amount: number) => {
    let list = [];

    // This is where I generate the tabs and name them
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      list.push(<StyledTabs onClick={() => setTab(i)}>Tab {i + 1}</StyledTabs>);
    }
    return list;
  };

  const current = useMemo(() => childrenList[tab], [tab]);
  const tabs = generateTabs(childrenList.length);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{tabs}</div>
      <div>{current}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabs;

const StyledTabs = styled.button`
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
`;
```

And this is where it's being used:

```
...
return (
        <Tabs>
          <div>
            <h1>THIS IS TAB 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
           <h1>AND HERE'S TAB 2</h1>
          </div>
        </Tabs>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the title of the child using: `child.props.title`. [Get child property in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328063/get-child-property-in-react)

```
  const tabs = childrenList.map((child,idx)=>{
    const title = (child as any).props.title ?? idx;
    return ( <StyledTabs key={title}  onClick={() => setTab(idx)}>{title}</StyledTabs>);
  })
```

Here's a working sandbox for the code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/read-child-props-n5f8y?file=/src/Tabs.tsx

As a note, I got rid of the useMemo as it didn't seem to be doing much and could cause stale values of the current to be displayed because you weren't using `childrenList` in the dependency array (which would've caused it to rerun every render).

I also added a key to your tabs to prevent react from complaining about that.

I also went ahead and just turned your generateTabs function into a single map as it's a little more clear than using a for loop and array push.